# Arduino to Android: Reading from bluetooth input executes twice when .print is only executed once in arudino

Tags: android, arduino

I'm writing a program in android that comminicates with an arduino two ways. When communicating back to the android I'm using .print to write to the serial port back to the android. But what happens is that android registers two messages. If the first message is "message" the first message is "m" and the other is "essage" why is splitting the message?

Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int rx = 2;
int tx = 3;

SoftwareSerial bt(tx, rx);

int led1 = 10;
char data = 0;  

bool room1on;

void setup() {

bt.begin(9600);

bool room1on = false;

pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  if (bt.available() > 0) {
    data = (char)bt.read();
    if(data == '1'){
      if(room1on){
        digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
        bt.print("room1;OFF");
      }
      else if(!room1on){
        digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
        bt.print("room1;ON");   
      }
      room1on = !room1on;   
    }
  }
}
```

android code:

```
package com.example.beyu.benapp4;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private BluetoothDevice btDevice;
    BluetoothSocket btSocket;
    Handler btHandle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ba != null) {
            if (!ba.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }

            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = ba.getBondedDevices();
            // If there are paired devices
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                // Loop through paired devicesUUID.randomUUID()
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    if(device.getName().equals("HC-06")){
                        btDevice = device;
                        try {
                            btSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(btDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                            btSocket.connect();
                            new ConnectedThread(btSocket).start();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) { }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        btHandle = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                String m = (String) msg.obj;
                //TextView tw = (TextView)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(textview, "id", getPackageName()));
                //if(tw != null)
                //    tw.setText(message);
            }
        };
    }


    public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {

        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = btSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer);
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    btHandle.obtainMessage(0, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void toogleRoomOne(View view){
        try {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write('1');
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When "1" is sent to the ardunio, android response like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post your android code as text.

Comment: `Reading from serial input` ??? This looks more like a bluetooth connection.

Comment: @greenapps changed and added.

Comment: `If the first message is "message"`. Do you mean If the first message is "room1;OFF" ? If so then say so.

Comment: `input executes twice`. Think you mean that messages come in fragmented.

Comment: @greenapps the messages comes in fragments as two messages from the inputstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your messages come in fragmented. This is quite normal for TCP connections. You have to concatenate them together to get the original message.

For that you have to know the end of the message. One would use a message separater character for that.

You can make it yourself easy to send a newline char after every message string. For instance "lamp1;ON\n". You send a line then.

At receiving side you can wait for a \n to come in but much easier is to read a line with `.readLine()`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.